# How to import a >300Mb database using XAMPP?

Tags: database, xampp

Whenever I try to upload a large, I get this:

`You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.`

Is there by chance a way to change this? I've google it but nothing found (unless about old versions old xampp).

Comment: Did you try cmd prompt upload(you are asking local machine right)

Comment: No, I didn't. Could you please tell me the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Via SSH CLI

Typically you want to SCP (secure copy) the SQL file to the server and run the `mysql` client to import the SQL script.

To send the file to the server, one would use this command:

```
scp dump.sql username@my-server.com:
```

Then you would SSH to `my-server.com` and run the following command to import your database:

```
mysql my_database < /path/to/dump.sql
```

`mysql` is the MySQL CLI client application (For Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`)

`my_database` is the name of the database you want to import into

`/path/to/dump.sql` is the file path to the SQL dump file

---

#### Alternative via GUI Application

If you have a user account that can access from anywhere, you could use MySQL Workbench ( https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ ) to do the import through a GUI application.

Comment: 1st part ok but 2nd part...

USER@USER-PC c:\xampp
# mysql tatoeba_database.sql < C:\xampp\mysql\data\tatoeba
Access is denied.

USER@USER-PC c:\xampp
# mysql -u root tatoeba_database.sql < C:\xampp\mysql\data\tatoeba;
Access is denied.

USER@USER-PC c:\xampp
# mysql tatoeba_database.sql < C:\xampp\mysql\data\tatoeba;
Access is denied.

USER@USER-PC c:\xampp

Comment: the gist > https://gist.github.com/RyckRichards/b0ef6478c335539424f2ff07fb171473

Comment: If you're using Windows, and it's on your local machine, just install MySQL Workbench and use it to do the import.  Install it, connect to the database server with it, and then there is an import option.

Comment: Oh, perfect! Thanks a lot for that!
I've just download. mysql-installer-community-5.7.17.0